# What are the best practices for making a website usable and consistent across all devices and screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

Confused regarding best methodology to make  website usable and consistent across all devices - Desktops, Netbooks or Ipads and Mobiles(mostly smart phones).

I'm not a Front End Developer or Designer so i'm not sure what is the best thing out there.

I've been reading on  Liquid Layouts, Keeping 2 different version of style sheets(1 for screen and 1 for hand held devices) and CSS Media Queries.

I'm not sure which one of these is the best fit to provide a consistent experience to the users of my site  whether they're on smart phones(any android, BB, iphone, Nokia) netbooks or desktops.

Please help.

Comment: I think is a really broad topic, maybe you could add something about the site you are thinking about. Whatever method you choose I believe you should adhere to standards and keep everything as simple as you can. Also you should use gracefull degradation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system

Comment: just a normal listings site...

Comment: Maybe it is worth looking at how Wordpress does it with plugins/templates.  It can be hard to do it all in CSS.

Comment: I'm still reading on all the suggestions... would select an answer when i'm done.  Thanks all for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've gathered (been researching it myself) it's really a combination of everything. Liquid layouts work great for different monitor sizes, while media queries help target mobile and tablet devices. I've been looking the [978 Grid System](http://978.gs/) to format a few websites I'm working on. It has grids for several devices, but part of me thinks it might be a bit too bulky for what I want to do.

Comment: +1 i'm still reading on the topics... would select an answer when i'm done.  Thanks  for answering.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comment, I think you should keep things as simple as you can and comply with good standards as HTML and CSS.

Let the browser / user choose the best way to use your site.

Also keep in mind [graceful degradation](http://accessites.org/site/2007/02/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/) / [progessive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement) and a logical structure that supports the pages.

Comment: progressive enhancement & graceful degradation are big!

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

> Fluid grids, flexible images, and
>   media queries are the three technical
>   ingredients for responsive web design,
>   but it also requires a different way
>   of thinking. Rather than quarantining
>   our content into disparate,
>   device-specific experiences, we can
>   use media queries to progressively
>   enhance our work within different
>   viewing contexts. That’s not to say
>   there isn’t a business case for
>   separate sites geared toward specific
>   devices; for example, if the user
>   goals for your mobile site are more
>   limited in scope than its desktop
>   equivalent, then serving different
>   content to each might be the best
>   approach.
>
> But that kind of design thinking
>   doesn’t need to be our default. Now
>   more than ever, we’re designing work
>   meant to be viewed along a gradient of
>   different experiences. Responsive web
>   design offers us a way forward,
>   finally allowing us to “design for the
>   ebb and flow of things.

There is a good free introductory video on [Think Vitaimin](http://membership.thinkvitamin.com/library/responsive-web-design).

[Responsive Web Design: Fundamentals : Introduction](http://membership.thinkvitamin.com/library/responsive-web-design/fundamentals/introduction)

Watch until about 3/4 the way through, where they start demonstrating what they are talking about.

Comment: +1 i'm still reading on the topics... would select an answer when i'm done.  Thanks  for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I think that liquid layouts are the best because they are the most cross-platform and are very easy to do. I use them on every site I make.

Comment: not sure if all mobile devices read normal style sheets?  I mean normal but liquid as i read somewhere that some mobiles only support style sheets specifically written for hand held devices.

Comment: @user481913 this isn't true, all mobile devices that accept any stylesheets will accept all stylesheets.

Comment: liquid layouts don't always work for very small devices (phones). It's best to also use `@media` to serve style sheets to specific devices.

Answer (score 0):

Even among tablet devices the difference in screen size and screen resolution can require different fonts size and link spacing, for legibility of the font and the accurate touchability of the links. Pages that render on the 10" iPad legibly may be difficult to read and clumsy to use on a 7" tablet. The 7" tablet might make you feel as though you had fingers like Shrek. This just happened to me recently when I used a 7" tablet to look at a site that I'd modified to work well on the iPad. Too tiny to read on the 7" tablet, and you don't always want your 7" tablet users to be pinch-zooming just so they can read your page and interact with it. You must determine the size of the target screen and employ appropriate CSS styling for that form-factor, and you may also be required to reduce the amount of content and/or to provide alternate mode of navigation for the smaller and smallest form-factors. Dynamically-served form-factor-specific content may be required, or highly granular control of content visibility using CSS.

I'd start with pages that have an "airy" look -- avoiding pages that have too much content and are too "busy".